# Lightning components - Button to call a method from the helper?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, helper

I'm doing [this Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/fr/content/learn/modules/lex_dev_lc_basics/lex_dev_lc_basics_server).

Basically, the idea is to have one component that include a form, a button to submit the form, and a child component that display the list of items.

I'm trying to improve the basic component with adding buttons, I think it's useless to copy the whole code, but fragments could help :

- my three buttons :

  ```
                <!-- BOUTON submit-->
                  <lightning:button label="Create Expense"
                                    class="slds-m-top--medium"
                                    variant="brand"
                                    onclick="{! c.clickCreate}"/>

                  <!-- BOUTON delete-->
                  <lightning:button label="Delete Expenses"
                                    class="slds-m-top--medium"
                                    variant="brand"
                                    onclick="{! c.clickDelete}"/>
                  <!-- BOUTON Reinitialize-->
                  <lightning:button label="Reinitialize form"
                                class="slds-m-top--medium"
                                onclick="{! c.helper.initForm }"/>
              <!-- / CREATE NEW EXPENSE FORM -->
  ```

The controller clickCreate function :

```
clickCreate : function(cmp, event, helper) {

    // tcheck validité du formulaire
    if( !helper.isValidForm(cmp)) {
        console.log('--Erreur de datas dans le form--');
        return;
    }

    // recuperation méthode APEX
    var action = cmp.get('c.saveExpense'); //console.log('action vide ? : ' + action);
    var newExp = cmp.get('v.newExpense');

    // ajout du paramètre
    action.setParams({
        'ex' : newExp
        // 'expArray' : newExp
    });

    // console.log('--clickCreate-- action.setParams : ' + JSON.stringify(action.getParam('ex')));
    // console.log('--clickCreate-- action.setParams : ' + JSON.stringify(action.getParam('expArray')));

    // définiton du callback
    action.setCallback(this, function(resp) {
        var state = resp.getState();
        console.log('saveExpense -- resp.getState() : ' + state);

        // console.log('resp[0] : ' + resp.getReturnValue()[0]);

        if (cmp.isValid() && state.toUpperCase()==='SUCCESS') {
            // rappel de la fonction doInit en fin de compte ?!
            console.log('--call doInit for refreshing the list -I know it's bad');
            let initAgain = cmp.get('c.doInit');
            $A.enqueueAction(initAgain);

            // reinitialiser le formulaire
            helper.initForm(cmp);

        } else {
            console.log('Err d\'insert de l\'expense avec statu : ', state);
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

And the helper initForm function :

```
initForm : function (cmp) {
    var form = cmp.set('v.newExpense', { 'sobjectType': 'Expense__c','Name': '','Amount__c': 0.0, 'Client__c': '','Date__c': '', 'Reimbursed__c': false });
}
```

So the clickCreate allows to create the expense and to add it to the list, and also to reinitialize the form with blank values calling the helper initForm() function ;

The thing is I'm unable to call the initForm() method in order to assign it to the third button...

This line is not working : `onclick="{! c.helper.initForm }"/>`

I got ideas, but I'm not happy with it (copying the method from the helper really isn't a solution),
What would be the best way to achieve my goal ?

Thanks !!

Nb : for the record the form look like this :
[image]

Comment: you need to declare a method in the controller that calls the helper, not invoke the helper directly on button click

Comment: Oh really ? I understand the logic behind, but it's sad in this use case. So, the best way is to add (and affect to the onclik) this method : 
    initForm : function (cmp, event, helper) {
        helper.initForm();
    }


??

Comment: avoid using the same name in your controller and helper, idk, callInit : function(cmp, event, helper){ helper.initForm();}

Comment: Sure, good advice I was focused on the logic. Thanks anyway !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare a method in the controller that calls the helper, not invoke the helper directly on button click.

Additionally, avoid using the same name in your controller and helper functions.

ex.

```
callInit : function(cmp, event, helper){ 
               helper.initForm();
            }
```

Comment: Thanks, did it ! (why duplicating your comment ?)

Comment: Just formalized the answer so the question can be marked as accepted